# Insert date via text expansion / shortcut key

Tags: macos

I've been using aText which is a small text expansion app for this - it's become pretty ropey on new OSX versions so I've given up. I've also been using the trial of the new [TextExpander](https://smilesoftware.com/textexpander) which is great, though it's billed monthly now and seems like overkill considering all I want to do is insert a date! My requirement is: if I type a short string like 'dd' or use a certain keyboard shortcut combination, I should have today's date output like so:

[ Jul 8 ]

I've fiddled with apple scripts etc to try and get this working, but no luck. Surely there's something out there that I've missed. Or a better Applescript that actually works :)